# PHP isset $_session equal to string

Tags: php, session, isset

So guys I'm new to PHP OOP

I make Login with Roles, and make function(checkrole) for knowing what role it is.

This is how my function looks like

```
public static function hasadmin()
{
  if(session_id() == '') {
  session_start();
  }
  if(isset($_SESSION['role']) == 'A') {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and call it into navbar partial :

```
<?php if (helper::login() == true && helper::hasadmin() == true) { ?>
<li style="float:\right"><a href="?controller=auth&action=logout">Logout</a></li>
<li><a href="?controller=admin&action=petugas">Petugas</a></li>
<li><a href="?">Laporan</a></li>
```

Function `helper::login` works perfectly.
 Every time I login with another role the partial (petugas, laporan)
still comes out.

Comment: Where do you set your `$_SESSION['role']`?

Comment: @RemcovanOs at loginpost phase

Comment: see @chris85's comment for the solution.

Comment: @chris85 i do, it doesn't work

Comment: @haikalhikmi You tried it as my answer is?

Comment: @RemcovanOs when i echo $_SESSION['role'] it return 'A' when i try equal it ike hasadmin() function it doesn't work

Comment: @chris85 thank's' it work glad you solve it :)

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['role']) == 'A')` that doesn't work, you're right and is a false positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset` returns a boolean. Run the `isset` **and** check the actual value.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'A') {
```